# Overflow td content over to the next td element without displacing in HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, overflow

Consider the following mockup -
[image]

The third column contains a button, which when clicked is replaced with a textbox and Save;Cancel button. The whole entity overflows over to the next td element, floating on top without displacing the button in the next td element. This is all being done in a `<table>` element.

Can someone suggest a way to achieve this?

Comment: It will be easy to help if you can share the code that you have tried

Comment: have you thought about using `colspan=2` to increase the third column to have the length of two columns and while doing so, removing the last column during the selection? or hiding

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```js
$(function() {
 $('input').on('focus blur', function(e) {
   var elem = $(this),
        td = elem.closest('td'),
        div = td.find('div');
        show = ( e.type == 'focus' );
    td.toggleClass('flowTD', show);
  div.toggleClass('flowDIV');
  });
});
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
td {
  padding: 0 .25em;
  height: 3em;
  border: 1px solid lightgreen;
}
input {
  width: 3em;
}
.flowTD {
  padding-top: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.flowDIV {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: lightblue;
  height: 3em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 3em;
  margin-left: -.25em;
  margin-top: -1px;
  padding: 0 .25em;
}
div input[type="submit"] {
  display: none;
  width: auto;
}
div.flowDIV input[type="submit"] {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>2749.5</td>
    <td>0.13</td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        <input type="submit" value="Cancel" />
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>buttons</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It will need some tweaking, but gives you a head start.

Answer (score 1):

You could create button for edit and then hidden input with  save and cancel buttons that will be shown on edit button click. Set it to absolute and thats it.

Something like this:

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>2749.5</td>
    <td>0.13</td>
    <td>
      <button class="click">3.5</button>
      <div class="show">
        <input type="text" class="showInput">
        <button class="save">Save</button>
        <button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button>></button>
      <button>||</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  width:450px; 
}

th,td {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  width:25%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

input {
  width: 80px;
}

.show {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top:15px;
  background: #F6FAFE;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.click').on('click', function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $('.show').show();
});
$('.save,.cancel').on('click', function() {
  $('.show').hide();
  $('.click').show();
});
```

You can test it here https://jsfiddle.net/azdfdss5/